# Location of Cisco VPN client profile configuration file (.pcf file) on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, cisco-vpn-client

What is the default location of Cisco VPN client profiles? I need those .pcf files since my old Cisco VPN client doesn't work after upgrading to [Mac OS X Leopard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mac_OS_X_Leopard) (version 10.5), and I don't remember my VPN settings.

Comment: Is the old Mac using the Cisco provided client?

Comment: Google brought me here when searching for the location in Windows 7. It is `C:\ProgramData\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I remember it right, they should be located in /etc/CiscoSystemsVPNClient/Profiles/ (you can open this folder from Finder´s Go To -> Go to Folder menu)

Comment: Not the answer see below with 39 up votes

Answer (score 63):

If, like me, you arrived here looking for the Cisco AnyConnect profile location, I found my config information at

**/opt/cisco/anyconnect**

I wanted this to be a comment on the accepted answer, but I bumped into the rep limit. If a mod wants to move this to the comments of the accepted answer, be my guest!

Comment: Exactly where it was for me too, thx.

Comment: for anyconnect 4 the profile files are XML

Comment: still the correct answer on macOS Catalina in 2021

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal and search for it (go ahead to the next line if the previous one doesn't find anything):

```
find ./Library -name '*.pcf'
find . -name '*.pcf'
find / -name '*.pcf'
```

If you don't find anything, check the Library folder inside your home directory. I think the Cisco client might import the settings and store it in some other format (or at least in another file) inside the Library or Library/Preferences folder.

Answer (score 0):

Path in Mac:
/opt/cisco/secureclient/bin/vpn

Sample command for connecting in terminal

```
$ cat ~/cisco_vpn.pvt | /opt/cisco/secureclient/bin/vpn -s connect <VPN_URL>

$ cat ~/cisco_vpn.pvt
<user_name>
<Password>
y
```